# Set builder notation for pairs?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a set $S$ of integers. I want to select the element pairs $(i,j)$ of it such that  $i=2*j$ and order of elements does not matter. How can I show it with the set builder notation ?

$\{\ (i,j)\ |\ i \in S\ \;and\;\ j \in S\; \ and\;i=2*j\}$ Is it correct and are there any ways to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not simply $$\{(2i,i) \mid i \in S\}$$?

Comment: @ClementC. What if $2i\notin S$

Comment: @RushabhMehta Good point. Then it's a bit less nice, indeed: $$\{(2i,i) \mid i \in S\}\cap S^2$$

Comment: More, that both are in the set S:  $~\{(2j,j): j\in S, 2j\in S\}$

Comment: @ClementC. I wouldn't really call that set builder notation

Comment: @GrahamKemp that's what I was thinking

Comment: what do you mean by "order of elements does not matter"? $(a,b)$ is notation for the *ordered* pair, where $a$ is the first element and $b$ is the second (so, if $a\ne b$, then $(a,b)\ne(b,a)$). If order does not matter, then we write instead $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: If order doesn't matter should it be "$i = 2j$ or $j = 2i$"?  Or, you could look at sets $\{i,j\}$ instead of ordered pairs $(i,j)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $\{\ (i,j)\ |\ i \in S\ \;and\;\ j \in S\; \ and\;i=2*j\}$ Is it correct and are there any ways to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

That is okay, although the use of words should be discouraged, and it can be compacted a bit more.   Any of the following should be acceptable:  $${\{(i,j)\mid i\in S, j\in S, i=2j\}\\\{(2j,j)\mid j\in S, 2j\in S\}\\\{(i,j) \in S^2 \mid i= 2 j \} \\\{(2j,j)\in S^2\}}$$

Sometimes there is a trade off between compactness and comprehensibilty.   Choose the version that you feel most clearly conveys the intended message.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you write: $\{(i,j) \in S^2| i= 2*j \} $

Comment: I don't think including $\in S$ in the left part of the set builder notation is considered appropriate, but I am not too knowledgeable on the subject.

Comment: @RushabhMehta It should be $\in S^2$, otherwise it is correctly placed.  $~\{(i,j) \in S^2 \mid i= 2\cdot j \} $ says: the set of pairs, $(i,j)$, drawn from the Cartesian square of $S$ such that $i$ equals twice $j$.

Comment: It should be $\in S^2$. And @RushabhMehta it is appropriate to put $\in$ there(some would even say it should be there) as without it it is not guarantee to be a set